# Silent catch exception in angular project I inherited

Tags: angular

I just inherited a new Angular project and I just find out errors and exception are not shown in console:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("before");
    throw new Error('An error occurred');
    console.log("after");
}
```

the console shows :

```
before
```

I suspect there is a silent catch exception somewhere.

I'm not proficient enough in Angular to know where to look, how would you debug this ? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, made a ctrl+shift+f "catch" and found the culprit.